# Stuck on this error code ENOENT: no such file or directory, after trying to run "Hello World" exercise

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having some trouble trying to run the "Hello World" exercise from the PluralSight tutorial. I'm new to coding and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I keep running into this error after entering the "npm run start" command in the terminal.

[image: I have a screenshot of the error message here]

I looked up possible solutions online, but they all range from deleting and reinstalling the package.json file to reinstalling git and node.js, etc. I should note that I'm working on a Mac, so I don't know if that's also part of the issue or something.

Here's the code

```
charlierodriguez@Charlies-Mac-mini ~ % npm run start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/charlierodriguez/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/charlierodriguez/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/charlierodriguez/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T17_59_28_824Z-debug.log
charlierodriguez@Charlies-Mac-mini ~ %
```

Comment: Is it an `.html` file or `.js` one ? the image shows an `.html` file and your post is tagged `nodejs`

Comment: This isn't the _code_, this is the output in the terminal when you run your code.  It would be helpful to see your actual code.
However, the error here is one that happens when you try to run `npm` from a directory that doesn't have an `package.json` file.

Comment: You need to run that command in the app directory. From the image i quess you should be in `/Users/charlierodriguez/web-dev-starter` so run `cd  web-dev-starter` and then `npm run start`

Comment: Ok, I did just that and I was able to get it to work! I was able to get it to work! Thank you! I just had to run it on the terminal on VS Code

Comment: !DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JS Starter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>                                                                                                                              And here's the code

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when npm is finding package.json file in that location and not able to find it. Can you run `js npm init`. It will create package.json file in that location.

You will still get some different error. As there should be a key **start** in script segment in package.json file. 
You can add that key with the value as command you want to run.